# How to cast to Number from String in java without knowing which number type is present in the String?

Tags: java

I am writing a compiler, that reads from an input file, parses it and creates various kind of tokens. Further, in parsing, upon getting a `NumLitToken` , I retrieve its's number value stored as `String` and want to save it as a `Number` for further stages of transformations. 
 
I am not aware whether the `String` contains `int`/ `float` / `long` / `double` etc. so i am using `NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(x)` method and expecting appropriate casted value, but i don't know why i am not getting a cast to `Integer` for int values.
Also, if there is any other way better to cast to `Number` from `String`, please enlighten me about it.

A small extract:

```java
import java.text.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        String x = "100";
        Number o  = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(x);
        System.out.println(o.getClass().toString());
        if(o instanceof Integer){
            System.out.println("int");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.Long
```

---

**UPDATE** : Turns out, the method only returns long or double. What to do to get appropriate cast to Number ? Is there a better way rather than trying to cast for every number type?

Answer (score 2):

Because the docs say so:

> Returns a Long is possible, otherwise a Double

Simple as that.

If you're just trying to parse an int, `int x = Integer.parseInt("500");` does the job!

Comment: docs only mention  `Returns a Long is possible, otherwise a Double` for the other overloaded parse method. Also, i dont know what type is present inside String, so i cannot directly use `Integer.parseInt` as it can also be a `Long`.

Comment: @DHS `NumberFormat.parse(String)` direct refers to that other method: _"See the [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)) method for more information on number parsing."_ So the description of the overloaded method also applies to this method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry, i just saw now. So what shall i do if i want appropriate cast ?

Comment: @DHS If you want an int, then use `Integer.parseInt`, the alternative is to use `Number.intValue()` (optionally after checking if it is actually in range for an int).

Comment: So you want a method call that returns an instance of `java.lang.Integer` for non-fractional inputs, unless that input is, say, `2^31` or higher, then it should return an instance of `java.lang.Long`. That sounds bizarre. I'm having a hard time imaging a properly designed solution that would require this. Perhaps elaborate on why you (think) you need this; it'll help with getting better answers at least, and may lead to a simpler alternate plan to solve the unstated problem you're having.

Comment: @rzwitserloot well, as i mentioned, am creating a compiler which emits JVM bytecode, upon getting an input such as `var x = 1000000000;` as a text file, i [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) it and then i need to know specifically if the var declared is int or long and then emit the JVM bytecode instruction accordingly. I think the requirement from String to Number is genuine, as the input itself will be a text file.

Comment: @DHS presumably something like `var x = 5.0;` means that x is a double and not an int even though it seems like it fits as an int. Also, in java, `var x = 238491420382104982;` is __not legal__ - it must be explicitly suffixed with an `L` to indicate 'this is a long', and no numberparser parses that `L`; that is a part of your lexer/parser stack.

Comment: I guess if you want to define your language such that 'var x = numbers;` means x is of type int if `numbers` fits, but is automatically changed to be of type long for larger inputs, and while you're at it... as a BigInteger if it is too large even for longs? That's.. creative, I guess. Then just write that, there isn't a tool I'm aware of that automatically returns the smallest matching type.

Comment: @rzwitserloot the programming language is not Java, i have designed my own dynamically typed language, and i allow user to declare variables as declared in python/ javascript, only common part with Java is the JVM bytecode. So upon getting a very large or decimal pointed number, i have to decide whether to declare it as Long or Double respectively using JVM bytecode instructions.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes exactly! thanks for your concern though! I really appreciate your help ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223695/discussion-between-rzwitserloot-and-dhs).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553023/822588) it is how it works.

If you want to a function that returns the most appropriate type depending its size the [apache-commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) `NumberUtils.createNumber` will do that for you.